# test the convergence of an infinite series

Tags: sequences-and-series

How to prove that the $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty} (1-e^{(-1/n^2)})$ series is convergent? I can not find a number to use the comparison test!

Comment: An alternate way to do this is to use the Limit Comparison Test with the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n^2}$.  (This comes from the idea that $e^x\approx 1+x$ for $x\approx0$.)

Answer (score 0):

***Hints:***

$$  e^{-x } = \lim_{n} \left({}1 - \dfrac {x} {n}\right)^n \ge  \left({}1 - \dfrac {x} {n}\right)^n  \ge 1 - n \cdot  \dfrac x n = 1 - x  \;\;\;\; \forall x \gt 0 \;\;\; $$

This is due to [Bernoulli's Inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli's_inequality) and due to the fact that the sequence $\lim_{n} \left({}1 - \dfrac {x} {n}\right)^n    $ is monotone increasing. Hence,

$$  e^{-\frac{1}{n^2}} \ge \left({}1 - \dfrac{1}{n^2} \cdot \dfrac {1} {n}\right)^n \ge 1 - \dfrac{1}{n^2} $$

Now you can apply the Comparison Test as you wish to do.